# Count comment threads, not total comments in a post

Tags: comments, count, threading

For a post I'd like to count the comment threads and not include nested replys in the count.

Currently I'm using a simple comment count, [`comments_number( $zero, $one, $more );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number)

What would be the best way to get the number of comment threads in a post?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, must be used in the loop:

```
<?php

// type = comment will only get "real" comments, no ping-/trackbacks
$comments = get_comments(array('type' => 'comment'));

$threads = 0;
foreach($comments as $comment) {
   // if the comment has no parent, it´s the first of a thread
   if($comment->parent == '') { $threads++; }
}  

switch($threads) {
   case 0: echo "There are no comments so far."; break;
   case 1: echo "There is one thread..."; break;
   default: echo "There are '.$threads.' comment threads going on."; break;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks,  

How would I format this complete it to just replace the existing format of?
    <?php comments_number( $zero, $one, $more ); ?>

Comment: I updated my code. Basically, the thread count is saved in `$threads`, so you can use it in several different ways...

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, I´d enjoy if you mark my answer as the right solution.